# Given a list of numbers, determine whether it can represent the pre-order traversal list of a binary search tree (BST)

Tags: preorder

Given a list of numbers, determine whether it can represent the pre-order traversal list of a binary search tree (BST).

```
public boolean isValid(int[] arr)
    {

        int root = arr[0];
        int i=1;

        while(  i< arr.length && root >arr[i])
        {
            i++;
        }

        for(;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i] <root)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }   

        return true;
    }
```

The above function works for most of the cases ex `{3,4,5,1,2}`, `{3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 6}`, `{1,2,3}`.
But it doesn't work for `{1,3,4,2}`.

Can anybody help me to fix the issue.

Comment: what is the language?

Comment: I think that your approach is not the best way to do it. Maybe the assignment can be read as "given L try to build a BST"

Answer (score 0):

The Idea is take a list of more that 3 elements you can identify `left`, `right` and `root` in a BST like the first three elements. Now it is a pre-order if and only if `left<=root<=right`. Now `root` go in to the stack and take the next 3 and apply the same logic.

Make this till you have less than three element:

1. Two elements become `left` and `root` with the rule `left<=root`
2. One element is just a `root`

In both cases you must put `root` in stack.

Now take the stack and apply the same logic ... till you have just one element in the stack that means it is a pre-order BST.

Now write it as recursive function is pretty trivial and funny.